What is the current guidance for async/await APIs to replace .NET events?
Consider the case of a library intended for use with other projects, which could be console applications, other class libraries, or applications with a UI. This library allows the user to send commands to and receive responses from a remote end point, but can also receive event messages from the remote end point. It is a valid use case that the user may send a command in response to a remote event. The transport mechanism uses async/await methods for transferring data to and from the remote end (e.g., using a WebSocket). In a "classic" .NET application, I might design an API like the following (Important note: Code presented herein is not canonical, probably won't compile as-is, and is written for discussion purposes only):
private Command currentCommand;

public event EventHandler<EventReceivedEventArgs>? EventReceived;

public CommandResponse ExecuteCommand(CommandParameters parameters)
{
    currentCommand = transport.SendData(parameters.Serialize());
    return currentCommand.WaitForCommandResponse();
}

protected void OnEventReceived(EventData eventData)
{
    if (this.EventReceived is not null)
    {
        this.EventReceived(this, new EventReceivedEventArgs(eventData));
    }
}

private void DataReceiver()
{
    // Example only. In a real app, there would be some terminating
    // condition here.
    while (true)
    {
        // For discussion purposes, assume this an API that returns data
        // from the remote end. How it works and how it is parsed can be
        // considered an implementation detail.
        byte[] receivedData = transport.ReceiveData();
        ParsedData parsed = Parse(receivedData);
        if (parsed is CommandResponse)
        {
            this.currentCommand.SetResponse(parsed);
        }

        if (parsed is EventData)
        {
            this.OnEventReceived(parsed);
        }
    }
}

However, given that I've heard repeatedly (and today, somewhat pointedly), ".NET events don't work with async/await," "Don't use async void, ever," and, "Don't mix synchronous and async code." So given the async/await form of the API looks like:
private Command currentCommand;

// This, right here, I'm told, is bad, bad, bad. Totally suspect.
// Poor API design choice. Don't do it. This API, and it's caller
// below are presented merely as placeholders for discussion.
public event EventHandler<EventReceivedEventArgs>? EventReceived;

public async Task<CommandResponse> ExecuteCommandAsync(CommandParameters parameters)
{
    await transport.SendCommandAsync(parameters.Serialize());
    return await transport.WaitForCommandResponse();
}

protected void OnEventReceived(EventData eventData)
{
    if (this.EventReceived is not null)
    {
        this.EventReceived(this, new EventReceivedEventArgs(eventData));
    }
}

private async Task DataReceiver()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await byte[] receivedData = transport.ReceiveData();
        ParsedData parsed = Parse(receivedData);
        if (parsed is CommandResponse)
        {
            this.currentCommand.SetResponse(parsed);
        }

        if (parsed is EventData)
        {
            this.OnEventReceived(parsed);
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

I totally understand why this is suboptimal. The event handler of the consumer will block the producing method. It might hang or be very long-running. It might throw. There are any of a myriad of things that might be problematic with this style of API.
But here's the operative question: What's the alternative? What does the .NET developer community recommend as a way to surface this type of capability to the user instead of using .NET events?

Have you looked at Microsoft's Reactive Framework?

I'm also not sure what you're considering as bad? That events get raised in async methods? There's nothing bad about that. I'm missing the point of your post.


.NET events don't work with async/await

They're not a natural fit, no. Most events in .NET have void as a return type, and the natural return type for an asynchronous method without a return value is Task, not void.
That said, there are various ways to make asynchronous events work. You can define a delegate with a Task return type, and declare an event with that delegate type. Or you can use deferrals. Or async void. Each of these can be valid solutions for using async/await with event handlers depending on your use case.

Don't use async void, ever

The guideline I usually give is "avoid async void". It's not a hard-and-fast rule. In fact, for UI events in particular, async void is usually what you do want to do.

Don't mix synchronous and async code

Definitely valid. No argument here.

What's the alternative? What does the .NET developer community recommend as a way to surface this type of capability to the user instead of using .NET events?

First, I recommend deciding whether you want to use a producer/consumer pattern, an Observer pattern, or a Strategy pattern. When writing synchronous code, Observer and Strategy are often confused and events are commonly used to implement either one. Technically, events should be used for Observer and something else (e.g., interfaces or overriding derived methods) used for Strategy. And producer/consumer usually uses a threadsafe queue in between the producer(s) and consumer(s).
If what you have is actually a Strategy pattern, then scrap the event outright and replace it with an interface. Interfaces can easily define asynchronous methods. But if you have an Observer or producer/consumer, read on.
In the Observer situation, you can think of your library as a producer of events, which can have listeners. With this perspective, you're dealing with a stream of events - or an "event stream". (Note that my usage of "event" as a noun here has nothing to do with event in C#; "event" in this paragraph refers to each data message that arrives).
Rx (Reactive Extensions) is a literal interpretation of the Observer pattern. From a theoretical perspective, it is a fantastic replacement for C# events. Unfortunately, the learning curve is considerable, so in reality it hasn't gained traction in the .NET community. Rx also has some rough corners with regards to async handlers: it has many of the same problems as a straight-up void-returning event. In general, I usually don't recommend it these days.
There are also the event-with-unusual-delegate approaches: both Task-returning and deferrals. I cover these in more detail in a blog post if you're interested.
But I'm guessing that the pattern you really want is producer/consumer. Producer/consumer can be distinguished from Observer in that items are only consumed once in producer/consumer, whereas in Observer the same item is "broadcast" to all listeners. For the producer/consumer pattern, the best approach would be Channels.
System.Threading.Channels provide Channels, which you can treat as an asynchronous producer/consumer queue. Your code is still producing a stream of events; they would flow into a queue (I recommend using a bounded channel). Then you can expose the reading side of that queue to your consumers as an IAsyncEnumerable<T>, which your consumers can more naturally consume using await foreach. This kind of "pull" API (as opposed to the "push" notification API used by events and Rx in the Observer pattern) is easier for consumers to deal with.
Side note: if your commands and their responses can be correlated with some identifier (which is usually the case in these kinds of protocols), then consider using a (concurrent) dictionary of active commands rather than just a single currentCommand. That will allow your consumers to have multiple commands in flight.
I have a (very long - sorry!) video series on developing an asynchronous TCP/IP client/server. Much of it (TCP/IP and socket programming) wouldn't be relevant to you (since you're using WebSockets), but I do show how to use Channels as streams of messages as well as the concurrent-dictionary-of-active-commands technique.

This, right here, is exactly the kind of answer I’m looking for. You already anticipated one of the things I implemented before posting here (the ConcurrentDictionary of in-flight commands). For the actual propagation of the events, yes, producer-consumer is what I need, and am already using a Channel for that. As for how users would be notified of events, it feels like the Observer pattern is probably closer to what users would expect. This is already the direction I was leaning, so I’ll play around with that. Thanks very much for the insight and ideas.


.NET events don't work with async/await

True

Don't use async void, ever

True, except when you're forced to by events in legacy technology (Winforms, your code, etc). See above.

I totally understand why this is suboptimal

To be absolutely clear, your example Task code is very, very bad. For many more reasons than what you listed. And in fact, you didn't even address what you seemed to want to improve, events. You have the exact same event API as the non-task version, just with worse code that doesn't even compile anymore.
Two points to help you guide towards a cleaner API:

The fact that events "don't work" with tasks (read: they leak continuations out of the original call) doesn't seem to apply in your case. You're just triggering the event with a copy of the data (the serialization result), so even if you lose your stack frame it's not like your parameter will get GC'd. So you're fine.

The modern C# task-aware events are encapsulated in MVVM ICommand implementations, for example ReactiveUI's ReactiveCommand or Community MVVM's RelayCommand. Both (and others) have full support for async backing functions and correctly handle disabling the command while it's running, for example.



Yes, the included code is bad. I was unclear that this is the case, and is presented merely for purposes of discussion. Mea culpa. I've edited to add a few disclaimers to that effect.
